# problems installing scipy and pybrain in python 3.5.1

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

it's my first post here, however i have used this site as a guest through google searches. to the point now. i am learning python and i want to install scipy and pybrain. i have python 3.5.1 installed in the following path

> C:\Program Files\Python35-32

When i use `pip install` (in cmd), I get an error with red letters, something along the lines of `failed with error code 1`. I've searched all around the web through google (mostly) and of course here but i can't find any solution.

I should say i have windows vista 32bit.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Tell exactly what the error message is, when pip fails it gives you a log file.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your reply. I don't know where the log file is. I checked the paths that were in the red text but i couldn't find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're beginning I suggest you to install one of the distributions linked on Scipy website : https://www.scipy.org/install.html

I use Anaconda : it provides Spyder and multiple libraries to help you start with.

About your problem, you may need to be a bit more specific with the error code you get during the installation.

Comment: i don't want to install any distribution. i've used enthough canopy in the past though. isn't it possible to install scipy withouth a distribution?

i could write the whole message if necessary but i guess that the log will be more of use. how can i find it though? i can't find it anywhere. any help with that? thanks again for all the replies!

Answer (score 0):

@ Pierre-Louis Sauvage, @ geo: anaconda is useful, yet it is also a fairly heavy application, with about 300MB memory needed. You may therefore want to consider miniconda first. Since you're learning Python, that will most likely be sufficient.

So, I write this in 'answer' format instead of comment, since I have not enough reputation points to write a comment.